# How to programmatically change filenames on S3 to remove filename extensions?

Tags: java, amazon-s3

Lets say you have a bunch of images which you want to host on S3 and they are available in various formats: png, jpg, jpeg, gif ... etc.

Writing or using an image-processing service to normalize all image formats, down to a single one, is one approach ... but I'm wondering if its possible to use a shortcut where you can remove the extension name from a filename (after upload) because the file properties now hold the appropriate mime-type anyway?

So after I upload 1.png, 2.jpg, 3.jpeg and 4.gif ... why not programmatically change all filenames to remove the extensions and access the images as:

- /my-bucket/1
- /my-bucket/2
- /my-bucket/3
- /my-bucket/4

So, how can someone programmatically change filenames on S3 to remove filename extensions?

I would love to hack on this using [substitutions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSImportExport/latest/DG/ManipulatingS3KeyNames.html#WorkingSubstitutions) to remove extensions `.<ext>` from filenames but I think that [programmatically](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSImportExport/latest/DG/GScreateanimportjobusingJava.html) its only available for setting up a job for transferring data from devices that you will actually ship to Amazon.

Comment: Is it necessary to do this in Java?  It's certainly possible, but it's a one-liner to do this in other languages.

Comment: I resorted to using [Cloudinary](http://t.co/JvuWNvifx1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not pretty, but it can be done by calling `copyObject()` for `/myBucket/myFile.jpg` and setting the new key to be `/myBucket/myFile`. After the copy is complete, delete the original. At this time I'm not aware of a proper "rename" method available.